# Fan dosnt work Packard Bell Easynote TE, Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: fan, heat

I have installed ubuntu alongside windows 8.1, when I use Windows the cooling fan works, but when i use Ubuntu the fan doesn’t work. What should I do? I don't want too over heat the laptop